# Ansible tower to manage hosts configured for pull mode?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I currently manage ~20 machines located around the world, behind a variety of firewalls using ansible operating in pull mode (all machines pull the playbook from a git+ssh repository). I'd like better reporting of the status of the machines so I am looking into Ansible Tower.

As far as I can tell Tower only supports push mode. The docs for ansible tower are not clear - can it also manage machines that run in pull mode? that is can each machine, for example, phone home to tower to retrieve configuration and report its results rather than requiring tower to push to those machines?

Alternative strategies using something like autossh + reverse tunnel are not options due to the variances of the remote machines firewalls and IT departments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "pull" with Tower is used to initialize machines- for instance, when AWS creates them with autoscaling.

Comment: yes, but it is my understanding that after the initial pull (or callback from the new host to tower) that tower then manages them via push, which is impossible due to my firewall configuration.

Comment: Aha. You're right- Ansible is agent less, it is designed around ssh push.